# Where to define permissions for user roles in FCKEDitor file uploads?

Tags: users, wysiwyg, files

There is this page where you upload files with FCKeditor
My admin user can do that , but I want the same for the Editor role 
(I already defined a profile for it)
It´s a matter of permissions and I´ve enabled all on the FCKEditor but I´m sure it´s something else...that I have to enable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the IMCE module for file uploads/directory? It could be a setting there that you need to enable.